# How to create a full circle by clicking its centre(every time the center is clicked individual sector of the circle is displayed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dot on the webpage. Every  time I click on the dot(considering it as the centre of the circle to be built) it displays individual sector of the circle. Thus I should get the full circle in the end. But with the following code I am only able to get the semi-circle and in the last click the flow is breaking. How will I implement  this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    background: #f00;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ten {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),
        linear-gradient(0deg, white 50%,transparent 50%);
}
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo" class="container ten">
  <div class="center">.</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $("#demo");
  var count = 0;
 
  $(".center").click(function(){
 if(count == 0)
  {
   
   x.css({'background-image':'linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%,transparent 50%)'});
   
  
   count =1;
  }
  else if(count == 1)
  {
 
   
   x.css({'background-image':'linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%,transparent 50%)'});
  
  count=2;
  }

  else if(count == 2)
  {
 
   
   x.css({'background-image':'linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%,transparent 50%)'});
  
  count=3;
  }
  else if(count == 3)
  {
 
   
   x.css({'background-image':'linear-gradient(270deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%,transparent 50%)'});
  
  count=4;
  }
  else
  {
   if(count==4){
   
   
     x.css({'background-image':'linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(270deg, white 50%,transparent 50%)'});
  }
   
  
   }
});
  
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You quit after count is 4, which is right after half of the circle is filled? If you want to fill the entire circle, you should continue your logic until you reach `count == 8`, since you always fill 1/8 of your circle

Comment: @AsheraH it looks like 4 "messes up"

Answer (score 0):

Following your code structure, I would play with background color and rewrite step 4 as follows.

```
x.css({
      'background': 'white',
      'background-image': 'linear-gradient(315deg, red 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(270deg, red 50%, transparent 50%)'
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/djhqvhs9/

Comment: I am already getting the desired result. Now I want to add separate text on individual sector  when an arrow key is pressed. Text should start from  the centre and go till the arc of the sector. How will I do this?

Comment: This is a different question you should probably close this one and open a new one with more details on where you are stuck.